# сохранение в Json

Tags: java, json

мне нужно сохранить файл в формате Json, чтобы потом при открытии я мог использовать данные которые сохранил, желательно сохранить файл в конкретную папку, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать Gson

```
    File folder = new File("d:/test");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(folder + "/test.txt", true)) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setPrettyPrinting()
                    .create();
            gson.toJson(obj, writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: а почему у меня toJson подчеркивается красным, и пишется "cannot resolve symbol toJson"?

Comment: Gson подключен? :)